# Trying to check in multiple photos at once, SP2010

Tags: check-out, picture-library, check-in, explorer-view

I created a photo library in SharePoint 2010 with LOTS of photos going into it. I use windows explorer view to drag photos from the server to the library. The photos all show checked out to me, and I want to check them in (and possibly disable the check-out/check-in feature altogether.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to check to ensure documents are not automatically checked out:

1) Go to the Library Settings and ensure there aren't any required fields

2) Go to the Library Settings > Versioning Settings.  Ensure content approval required is turned off and require check out is turned off.

To check-in the ones you already have checked-out, you will need to select them all in the web browser and click check-in on the ribbon.  Alternatively, you can use SharePoint Designer to connect to the site and check-in the items (this may be easier for you doing it in bulk).

Answer (score 0):

Also note that you should be able to select the items in the view and use the "Check in" option from the ribbon. Be sure to use a normal list type of view to do this. Perhaps you can create a view that filters items that are checked out to you filtered on your username and go from there.